# Link Product Attribute with multiple values - Woocommere

Tags: php, woocommerce

On my custom Single product page, I want to link every value of pa_ontwerper to the correct page. I used this code what works if pa_ontwerper has only 1 value:

`$ont = $product->get_attribute('pa_ontwerper');`

`echo "<a href='https://www.website.nl/attribute" . $ont . "/'>" . $ont . "</a>" ;`

This results in: designer1 with link to [www.website.nl/attribute/designer1/](http://www.website.nl/attribute/designer1/)

But when pa_ontwerper has for example 2 values, the output wil show something like:

designer1,designer2 with a link to [www.website.nl/attribute/designer1,designer2/](http://www.website.nl/attribute/designer1,designer2/)

Which is wrong.

What can I change in the code to make sure both values are linked correcly?

Comment: Seems like the attributes gets imploded, you can use strpos to check if there is a comma and do an explode. Could an attribute contain comma?

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is in the right direction. When I do an explode with this code

$pieces = explode(" , ", $ont);
echo $pieces[0]; // piece1
echo $pieces[1]; // piece2

The output is designer1, designer2. But how do I link them accordingly?